# How can I change another dataSource (not default c3p0) in Play 1.4.3

Tags: datasource, playframework-1.x

In Play 1.4.3, the default pool is `c3p0`. I wanna change it.

Something like follows:

```
db=java:/comp/env/jdbc/myDatasource@
db=jndi:jdbc/myDataSource
```

how can I config to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the pool would effectively mean changing the framework code itself, since it's "bundled" with Play.

One way to do this is to clone Play from GitHub (https://github.com/playframework/play1) so you can make whatever low-level changes you like.

Alternatively, you could look at the 1.5.x releases, which use HikariCP as the connection pool out of the box.